# C++ data members. Goal: Initialize in constructor then leave alone, will const work here?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, datamember

I have the following

```
    struct dweDMPair {
        const dweller   *occu;
        const double    sqDM;
        float   prob;
        dweDMPair(dweller *inOccu, double sqdm) : occu(inOccu), sqDM(sqdm) {}       };
```

I want to return an array of pointers to these objects but desire that they should not be accidentally deleted by the client. Or, err, maybe not, just trying this design iteration.

My question is, is there a (very concise and neat) way of specifying (as I have illustrated with a const prefix) that members are only ever assigned in the constructor?

I know private/public and interface/methods could sort this, but humour me, how far can the `const` keyword be exploited?

_***EDIT*_**

Nawaz, my goal is simply to initialize 2 of the 3 data members once only, in the constructor. Then I can export this instance as a const dweDMPair *ptrToVal so that the client cannot then call delete- because that won't work on pointers to const instances will it? The client will then proceed to give their own value for the third member `prob`. yeah, I know functions enforce protection but I want it faster.

The members can't be static but instance members. In case you were wondering..

Comment: The question is not clear. You should use more words to explain it

Comment: "I want it faster" - you want what faster?  I think you're worrying about speed problems where there probably aren't going to be any (in particular if you use inline functions).

Comment: @Michael, I need to change my avatar. I am writing a game, so there will _always_ be speed problems. I'll update my avatar when I get to that level of creativity that I have an image problem.

Comment: @John: I'm a little confused about the avatar comments - I didn't notice anything about your avatar, much less anything misleading. As far as speed problems, I understand there will always be speed problems - particularly in the gaming field. That doesn't mean that accessor functions to these fields will be one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clarify that what you really want is:

> Then I can export this instance as a const dweDMPair *ptrToVal so that the client cannot then call delete- because that won't work on pointers to const instances will it?

Delete can be called on pointers to `const` instances and it can be called on objects which contain `const` members. This use of `const` will not help you reach your goal.

Some example code that compiles without complaint:

```
struct dweller {
};

 struct dweDMPair {
        const dweller   *occu;
        const double    sqDM;
        float   prob;
        dweDMPair(dweller *inOccu, double sqdm) : occu(inOccu), sqDM(sqdm) {}       
 };

int main() {

    dweDMPair const* p = new dweDMPair(NULL, 3.14);

    delete p;
}
```

You might want to further clarify your end-goal (possibly in another question if it would change this one too much).

Comment: Thanks :) And apologies and thanks to AndrzejJ for not making myself clearer sooner.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, const does what you want. Note that what you do in the constructor initializer list is not assignment, it's initialization. You can't assign to const objects, but you can initialize them with a value.
Also, regardless of making them const, you might want to consider encapsulating these members in a class as private members. It's not much more typing, but it does improve maintainability.

Edit:

To define const pointer you do:

```
Type * const member;
```

not

```
const Type* member;
```

the second syntax is pointer to const type, not const pointer.

Comment: The second syntax is a pointer to a constant instance, which is what I declared. Do you mean that it _won't_ work as I can't even assign to it on initialization? And that it _will_ work if I use your first syntax (constant pointer)?

Comment: Technically, the pointer-to-const syntax means the type pointed to is `const Type` (`const dweller` in your example). The instance pointed to may or may not be const, but the pointer will treat it as such, e.g. not allow any modifying (non-const) operations on the referenced object. This is different than a const pointer, which is a pointer whose _value_ cannot be changed, i.e. cannot be re-pointed to a different object. You can combine both by using the syntax `const Type* const member` or `Type const* const member`.

Comment: With assignment my point was that assigning is a different operation than initializing a variable or member with a value. E.g. the statement `int i=3` may look to you like it has an assignment in it, but it really does not. Initialization is providing initial values to objects when they are constructed, i.e. they don't exist before and the initialization value is the first value they ever have. Assignment is changing the value of a previously existing object. What you do in the constructor initializer list is initialization, not assignment.